# merging list of dictionaries while merging the values of similar ke

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

i need to make a function that takes a list of dictionary and returns their sum,

for example

- in `[{(1,3):2, (2,7):1} , {(1,3):6}]` it needs to return `{(1,3):
  8, (2,7): 1}`
- if  their sum is `0` it removes the key from the
  dictionary. The problem here is that it returns `[(1, 3), 6]`

---

```
def swe(lst):
    s = []
    a = []
    v = []
    q = 0
    l = 0 
    for d in lst:
        s.append(d.keys())
        v.append(d.values())
    for i in s:
        for j in i:
            if len(i) == 1:
                a.append(j)
            if len(i) > 1:
                a.append(j)
                for t in a:
                    if a.count(t) == 1:
                        for q in range(len(v)):
                            for q in range(len(s)):
                                dct1 = v[q]
                                dct2 = s[q]
                                dct3 = dct2+ dct1
                                q = q+1
                                continue
                        return dct3
                    if a.count(t) > 1:
                        for l in range(len(a)):
                            dct5 = v[q]
                            dct6 = s[q]
                            dct7 = dct5 + dct6
                            l = l+ 1
    return dct7



print swe([{(1,3):2, (2,7):1} , {(1,3):6}])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quite hard to follow with the one letter variables names so I wrote something new which I think does what you want:

```
def merge_dictionaries(list_of_dictionaries):
    results_dict = dict()
    for dictionary in list_of_dictionaries:
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            results_dict[key] = results_dict.get(key, 0) + value

    return {key: value for (key, value) in results_dict.iteritems() if value != 0}


print merge_dictionaries([{(1,3):2, (2,7):1} , {(1,3):6 , (9,9) : 0}])
>>> {(2, 7): 1, (1, 3): 8}
```

It goes through each dictionary in your list and adds the value to the sum so far and then filters out answers with a sum of 0 at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for something like this:

```
def swe(lst):
    res = dict()
    for d in lst:
        for key,value in d.items():
            if key in res:
                res[key] += value
            else:
                res[key] = value

    for key,value in res.items():
        if value == 0:
            res.pop(key)

    return res
```